# array_search() function not search the value inside the array

Tags: php, arrays

I want the process the `country` array which is having the countryname, dialing code etc.
Below is my code. I want the `d_code` for all the respective country that i get in `$countryName` variable.

```
$countries = array();
$countries[] = array("code"=>"IN","name"=>"India","d_code"=>"+91");
$countries[] = array("code"=>"CA","name"=>"Canada","d_code"=>"+1");

if(search_array("$countryName",$countries));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through on your arrays. Your `$countries` array has arrays:

```
$countries = array();
$countries[] = array("code" => "IN", "name" => "India", "d_code" => "+91");
$countries[] = array("code" => "CA", "name" => "Canada", "d_code" => "+1");

var_dump(searchCountry("India", $countries));

function searchCountry($search, $countries) {
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        if ($country['name'] == $search) {
            return $country['d_code'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a closure with `array_filter` thus:

```
$countries = array();
$countries[] = array("code" => "IN", "name" => "India", "d_code" => "+91");
$countries[] = array("code" => "CA", "name" => "Canada", "d_code" => "+1");

$countries; // your array
$country_name = 'India'; // the value you are looking for
$filtered_array = array_filter($countries, function ($element) use ($country_name) {
    if ($element['name'] === $country_name) return $element['d_code'];
});

$filtered_array; //loop through this array for fields you want
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $countries = array();
    $countries[] = array("code"=>"IN","name"=>"India","d_code"=>"+91");
    $countries[] = array("code"=>"CA","name"=>"Canada","d_code"=>"+1");
    $d_code = search_array($countryName,$countries);
?>
```

Your `search_array` function can be like this

```
<?php
    function search_array($countryName,$countries){
        foreach($countries as $country){
            if($country["name"] == $countryName){
                return $country["d_code"];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: and what if no result? you need to return something, eg. false.

Comment: @lolka_bolka [you must not always return something](http://blog.gordon-oheim.biz/2013-03-13-Always-Return-Something/)